# How to localise parameters text in SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services)

Tags: text, reporting-services, localization, parameters

I have a report (*.rdl) which has a parameter named @UserId, and its text value (e.g. User in English). The Parameter text value (User) can be set in Prompt text field under Report Parameter Properties windows. The text value is used for report parameter on the top of a reprot.

**Possible soltuion**

**Option 1)**

The .rdl file is consumed by ASP.NET Web form ReportViewer. Thus, is it possible that the ReportViewer allows to change the parameter values programmatically.

**Option 2)**

What about change the parameter text on .rdl file directly programmatically.

**Settings**

SQL Server 2008 R2

Any idea would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A bug in SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Service.